# Syntax error in PARAMETER clause when passing through parameters as Decimal types using MS Access querydefs

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to write an insert query that takes financial data and writes it to my Access database from .net

The problem is that I cannot pass through my data via decimal datatype parameters despite being able to select them as Decimal datatype in the Ms Access parameters window, and despite the database being able to create table fields of Decimal datatype.

I was wondering, is what I am trying to do possible? If so how?

Here is a subsection of my query:

```
PARAMETERS pMidPrice Decimal;
INSERT INTO NonStandardPricingInstructions ( MidPrice)
SELECT pMidPrice as Expr1
```

If I change Decimal to IEEEDouble then it works, but I would prefer to pass through a Decimal if possible.

Many thanks

Comment: Just curious ... since you're dealing with financial data, why not use Currency instead of Decimal as the data type for `MidPrice`?

Comment: Hi Hans, yes I think you're right - that's the way to go, using a Decimal table field / Currency param datatype in Access and passing through the Decimal datatype from .net. I was just confused as to why I was getting this issue when trying to use Decimal as a parameter datatype when it looks like it's supposed to be possible.

Comment: Historically, Decimal data type was troublesome for Access, but I no longer recall the details as to why.  I think the situation has improved with more recent Access versions. Since you're using an older MDB version, that reinforces my hunch you should use Currency instead of Decimal.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I'll do that

Comment: Ah my mistake above, not a decimal datatype for the field, a currency datatype as well as a currency param datatype

Comment: So then does this query work in an Access session and then does it work when executed from VB.Net? ... `PARAMETERS pMidPrice Currency;
INSERT INTO NonStandardPricingInstructions (MidPrice)
VALUES ([pMidPrice]);`

Comment: Yes, that's working perfectly for me, with a Currency field in Access, executed from .net (oledb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work for me:

For a saved query in Access named [qryDecimalTest]:

```sql
PARAMETERS pDecimalColValue Decimal;
SELECT Clients.ID
FROM Clients
WHERE (((Clients.decimalCol)=[pDecimalColValue]));
```

the following C# code finds the record where the `Decimal` field is 3 and returns the correct ID value

```cs
cmd.CommandText =
    "SELECT ID FROM qryDecimalTest";
decimal queryParameterValue = 3;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = queryParameterValue;
var thing = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} ({1})", thing, thing.GetType().ToString()));
```

### Edit re: comments

I tried another test, but this time I used Jet.OLEDB against an Access 2000 .mdb file. I changed the saved query in Access to

```sql
PARAMETERS pMidPrice Decimal;
INSERT INTO NonStandardPricingInstructions ( MidPrice )
SELECT [pMidPrice] AS Expr1;
```

and used the following C# code

```cs
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText =
    "qryDecimalTest";
decimal queryParameterValue = 3;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = queryParameterValue;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

That worked fine, too.

Comment: Thanks Gord, what version of Access are you using? I'm wondering if my issue is a 2000 - 2002 mdb issue. Aye I've just checked and using your query I get the same error, "Syntax Error in Param clause"

Comment: @bamie9l I have updated my answer, although I see from the other comments that you'll probably switch to using `Currency`. That sounds like a good idea to me, too.

Comment: Thanks Gord, I think that my problems are an unusual case stemming from my using an old version of Access, as your solution will normally work I'll therefore mark your answer as the correct one, many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same issue as me, I've detailed a solution here: [Store more than four decimal places in an MS Access Currency field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834945/store-more-than-four-decimal-places-in-an-ms-access-currency-field/19835139#19835139)