# Store more than four decimal places in an MS Access Currency field

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to store price figures in my Access database and am using a Currency field (instead of Decimal) for reasons, including the fact I'm using an old version of Access that are detailed in this thread: [Syntax error in PARAMETER clause when passing through parameters as Decimal types using MS Access querydefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545327/syntax-error-in-parameter-clause-when-passing-through-parameters-as-decimal-type).

For consistency between systems I need to store the prices to 6 decimal places. However regardless of the settings I choose in Access, the values I type in are automatically rounded to 4 decimal places.

Here is the field in the table setup to 8 decimal places (I need 6 but was trying more in case):

[image: table field setup]

Here is the just entered, as yet unrounded figure:

[image: unrounded figure]

And after I press return, the value saves to the table, but rounded to four dps:

[image]

Is there any way to get MS Access to store currency datatypes to more than 4 decimal places? Am I doing something wrong?

Many thanks,

Jamie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone that has the same problem as me, I've solved it by using currency parameter types in the querydef and decimal fields in the table:

Decimal data type:

[image: Decimal data type]

Currency param:

[image: Currency param]

This gets over issues with the decimal param type (detailed here:[Syntax error in PARAMETER clause when passing through parameters as Decimal types using MS Access querydefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545327/syntax-error-in-parameter-clause-when-passing-through-parameters-as-decimal-type)) and issues with the currency field rounding to 4 dps http://msmvps.com/blogs/access/archive/2009/04/27/the-problems-with-currency-fields.aspx